# Replicar informaçao pelas colunas da tabela Angular JS

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-repeat

Tenho uma tabela no qual preciso de duplicar as colunas da tabela quando o  ID mude no array recebido.

O array é composto por `result=[{"id":"1","Dia":"250.0","inicial":"1050.0","final":"1050.0","DIAS":"800.0"},
{"id":"1","Dia":"250.0","inicial":"1050.0","final":"1050.0","DIAS":"800.0"},{"id":"2","Dia":"250.0","inicial":"1050.0","final":"1050.0","DIAS":"800.0"},{"id":"2","Dia":"250.0","inicial":"1050.0","final":"1050.0","DIAS":"800.0"}]`

```
<table  class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Inicio</th>
            <th>Fim</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="r in result">
            <td align="center">{{r.Dia}}</td>
            <td align="center">{{r.inicial}}</td>
            <td align="center">{{r.final}}</td>
            <td align="center">{{r.DIAS}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Para ficar algo assim do genero:

Tabela:

[image: Tabela a criar]

Comment: Dessa forma teria uma replicação de informação para as duas linhas de resultados?

Id1.dia e novamente Id1.dia um embaixo de outro, é realmente assim ?

Comment: sim porque o mesmo id pode receber valores diferentes, logo pode haver dados semelhantes, nesse array sao todos iguais so para exemplificar

Comment: Existe alguma regra para apresentar esses dados ?
Com qual regra você se baseou para definir que Id1 deve estar embaixo de Id1 ? Se tivesse mais 2 id sendo o valor deles 3 teria mais uma vez a réplica dessas colunas ?

Comment: sim, todos os dados do id1 ficam à direita e do id2 ficam à esquerda.
Pode receber no maximo até 2 id's ou seja pode só ter 1 id ou entao recebe 2 id's, nao mais que isso

Answer (score 4):

Para fazer da forma que você precisa recomendo que você construa o objeto já da forma que você necessita no servidor, já que serão dados que praticamente serão fixos, id=1 e id=2 sendo que o id=2 deve ficar a direita de id = 1.
    result = [ {"id1"="1", ..., "id2"="2", ...}, {"id1"="1", ..., "id2"="2", ...} ]

As reticências representam as propriedades restantes, respectivamente, recomendo apenas alterar a nomenclatura delas, para identificar o que seria id 1 e id 2.

HTML:

```
     <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Inicio</th>
        <th>Fim</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Inicio</th>
        <th>Fim</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="r in result">
        <td align="center">{{r.Dia1}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{r.inicial1}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{r.final1}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{r.DIAS1}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{r.Dia2}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{r.inicial2}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{r.final2}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{r.DIAS2}}</td>
    </tr>
```

Ao meu ver essa seria uma forma simples de ser resolvida conforme sua nova explicação.

Comment: O array é de objetos. Eu quero que o ID for 2 passe os seus dados à direita replicando as colunas 
Ex:

Tabela:

|dia      |inical    |final   |dias    | |dia   |inicial     |final     |dias|
--------------------------------------------------
id1.dia |id1.inicial | ...|.... | |id2.dia |id2.inicial   | ...   | ....|

Comment: Então acho que você não entendeu.
No caso o que você montou não é um array de objetos, é apenas um array.
Para ser um array de objetos você necessariamente precisa seguir o "modelo" que escrevi, colocando todos os resultados em forma de objetos. Por exemplo, você executa uma _query_ que retorna 30 registros do banco (30 linhas), cada coluna seria uma propriedade e cada registro seria um objeto, no angular você deve criar um array que encapsule tudo isso, logo um array de objetos.

Comment: O ng-repeat por si só irá gerenciar a iteração, que para cada loop que ele fizer será como se você estivesse navegando entre os registros retornados do banco.
`result = [ {"id"=2, "descricao"="registro 2"}, {"id"=3, "descricao"="registro 3"} ];`
Na primeira vez que o `ng-repeat` executar o apply no DOM irá imprimir: `<tr><td>2</<td><td>registro 2</td></tr>`
Na segunda vez que o `ng-repeat` executar o apply irá imprimir: `<tr><td>3</td><td>registro 3</td></tr>`

Comment: Esse array que meti era um exemplo apenas, o array é de objetos da forma como indicou, ele provem de um JSON logo ja vem formatado. A minha duvida é como meto os dados do id1 nas colunas da esquerda e o id2 nas colunas à esquerda que sao iguais as da esquerda quer que coloque uma imagem para perceber melhor?

Comment: Então, edite sua pergunta de forma que realmente ilustre o problema, pois do jeito que está a pergunta, a minha resposta solucionaria.
Recomendo que use uma imagem e coloque array que está recebendo realmente.

Comment: A pergunta foi editada

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30780/discussion-between-pnelson-and-felippe-tadeu).

Comment: Não será um boa solução, pois nao consigo editar o nome das variaveis que veem do JSON a unica coisa que posso pegar é atraves do ID